# Hive Wiring Advice - Combi Boiler

Tags: wiring, thermostat, boiler

I've just moved house and am trying to wire up the hive (as I did in my previous house with no problems). I have a combi boiler (Ideal Logic 30) and a single-channel hive receiver. The old thermostat (appears to be unbranded) has the live and neutral going to it from a fuse, which makes sense, but then it only has one wire going into it from the boiler.
[image: Old thermostat wiring]

Terminals 3 and 4 in the picture are the neutral and live from the power, terminals 5 and 6 are for an NTC thermistor which won't be needed anymore, and terminal 1 is the only one which physically comes from the boiler.

The brown in terminal 1 comes out of a twin & earth type cable, where the other 2 wires are not in use.

[image: Hive wiring diagram]
When I previously wired up the Hive in the old house, I used terminals N, L, 1, and 3. For this one, N and L I can obviously use, but I'm a bit confused about where the remaining wire from the boiler should go, and if I'm supposed to have another wire, need to use one of the others out of the twin & earth, or if the internal boiler wiring needs altering.

Things I have tried so far are:

N, L, and the brown in 1. The Hive powered up fine but it wouldn't turn the heating on and there was a message on the boiler saying "Winter setting timer or room stat off".

Then I tried the brown in 1, and took the unused blue from the twin & earth into 3. Same problem again. Finally I tried swapping 1 and 3 over, and still had the same problem.

Any ideas?